# Convert really big number from binary to decimal and print it

Tags: c, binary, decimal, bignum, bcd

I know how to convert binary to decimal. I know at least 2 methods: table and power ;-)

I want to convert binary to decimal and print this decimal. Moreover, I'm not interested in this `decimal'; I want just to print it.

But, as I wrote above, I know only 2 methods to convert binary to decimal and both of them required addition. So, I'm computing some value for 1 or 0 in binary and add it to the remembered value. This is a thin place. I have a really-really big number (1 and 64 zeros). While converting I need to place some intermediate result in some 'variable'. In C, I have an `int' type, which is 4 bytes only and not more than 10^11.

So, I don't have enough memory to store intermedite result while converting from binary to decimal. As I wrote above, I'm not interested in THAT decimal, I just want to print the result. But, I don't see any other ways to solve it ;-( Is there any solution to "just print" from binary?

Or, maybe, I should use something like BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) for intermediate representation? I really don't want to use this, 'cause it is not so cross-platform (Intel's processors have a built-in feature, but for other I'll need to write own implementation).

I would glad to hear your thoughts. Thanks for patience.

Language: C.

Comment: Just a question, how is this binary number stored?

Comment: It's not trivial to convert a random bit (or sequence of four bits) to a decimal digit.  The most well-known case where we *wish* we could do this is with the BPP algorithm for pi: You can compute any bit, or any *hex* digit, but you can't get the decimal digit using that algorithm (unless you want to do a huge conversion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Biggest standard integral data type is `unsigned long long int` - on my system (32-bit Linux on x86) it has range 0 - 1.8*10^20 which is not enough for you, so you need to create your own type (struct or array) and write basic math (basically you just need an addition) for that type.

If I were you (and memory is not an issue), I'd use an array - one byte per decimal digit rather then BCD. BCD is more compact as it stores 2 decimal digits per byte but you need to put much more effort working with high and low nibbles separately.

And to print you just add `'0'` (character, not digit) to every byte of your array and you get a printable string.

Comment: Yes, after the night, I've came to the same solution ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend using a library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) (GNU multiprecision library).  You can use the `mpz_t` data type for large integers, the various [import/export routines](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#Integer-Import-and-Export) to get your data into an `mpz_t`, and then use [`mpz_out_str()`](http://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html#I_002fO-of-Integers) to print it out in base 10.

Comment: Seconded. GMP makes this stuff easy.

Comment: I know about GMP well, but I isn't what I want.

Comment: Why do you not want GMP?  Does LGPL not work for you?  It takes about 3 function calls to achieve what you want (import, print, cleanup), and it'll be faster and less buggy than anything you can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when converting from binary to decimal, you really don't need ALL the binary bits at the same time. You just need the bits you are currently calculating the power of and probably a double variable to hold the results.
You could put the binary value in an array, lets say i[64], iterate through it, get the power depending on its position and keep adding it to the double.

Comment: Wouldn't you need a whole lot of them? 999999 is 0xf423f, but if you change one bit in the second least significant hex digit (so you have 0xf427f) every decimal digit changes and you get 1000063.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to decimal really means calculating each power of ten, so why not just store these in an array of bytes?  Then printing is just looping through the array.

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't you allocate memory for, say, 5 int's, and store your number at the beginning of the array?  Then manually iterate over the array in int-sized chunks.  Perhaps something like:

```
int* big = new int[5];
*big = <my big number>;
```