# Print int128 value from struct

Tags: c

I have this int128 that is a tuple of 2 64-bit integers:

```
struct int128 {

    uint64_t    left;
    int64_t     right;
};
```

I know how to make basic arithmetic like multiply, addition and subtraction, but I don't know how to print the current signed value in C.

Can someone show me please how to do that?

Comment: Can't you use a library for that?

Comment: I'm going to guess you need to write a bunch of functions to do that.

Comment: I want to learn how to do that ..

Comment: There are many [good C reference books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from.

Comment: How will you print an `int` value without using `printf()` family?

Comment: No, how can you print the value of this struct int128?

Comment: Do you know how to make a division with remainder in your 128 bit datatype? if so, you can extract decimal digits dividing by 10

Comment: typically those are called the high and low significant or most and least significant parts, not left and right

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a 128-bit integer to a decimal ascii string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023414/how-to-convert-a-128-bit-integer-to-a-decimal-ascii-string-in-c)

Comment: @Will Yes i made division arithmetic. Can you provide sample code to try?

Comment: @phuclv Thank you, but the code does not work with negative values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following function:

```
int64_t divideRem(struct int128 *number, int64_t divisor);
```

That divides number / divisor, setting the division result on number, and returns the remainder of the division.

You could use a recursive implementation:

```
printInt128rec(struct int128 *number) {
  int64_t rem;
  rem = divideRem(number, 10);
  if( cmpInt128(number, 0) != 0 ) { /* compares number with 0 */
    printInt128rec(number);
  }
  printf("%d", rem);
}
```

Your main print function should copy the number to avoid modifications, and check for negatives:

```
printInt128(struct int128 *number) {
  struct int128 copy = *number;
  if( cmpInt128(&copy, 0) < 0 ) {  /* number is negative */
    printf("-");
    becomePositive(&copy); /* copy = abs (number ) */
  }
  printInt128rec(&copy);
}
```

Now you may call printInt128 to print your numbers. Notice that I used several other functions that operates between an int128 integer and an int64. If you know how to make 128 bits arithmetics these should be easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you ! - i did the same before i saw your post. Happy that your solution confirm that i did the right thing :) -  once again thank you!